# path to html page using ring and gradle

Tags: gradle, clojure, ring

My folder structure looks like this

```
src
    main
        clojure
               .../core.clj
        webapp
              WEB-INF
                     index.html
```

In my `core.clj` I have a `main` function for jetty

```
(ns com.lapots.platform.web.core
    (:use ring.adapter.jetty)
    (:use com.lapots.platform.web.router.core)
    (:require [ring.middleware.reload :refer [wrap-reload]])
    (:import [org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler StatisticsHandler])
    (:gen-class))

(def a-minute 60000)

(defn conf
    [server]
    (let [stats-handler (StatisticsHandler.)
          default-handler (.getHandler server)]
        (.setHandler stats-handler default-handler)
        (.setHandler server stats-handler)
        (.setStopTimeout server a-minute)
        (.setStopAtShutdown server true)))

(def app
    (-> routes
        wrap-reload))

(defn -main [& args]
    (run-jetty app {:port 3000 :configurator conf :join? false}))
```

`router/core.clj` has this code

```
(ns com.lapots.platform.web.router.core
    (:require [compojure.core :refer [defroutes GET ANY]]
              [liberator.core :refer [defresource resource]]
              [ring.util.response :as resp]))

(defresource rest-handler
             :handle-ok "rest response"
             :etag "fixed-etag"
             :available-media-types ["text/html"])

(defn wrapped-file-response [request]
    (println "Attempt to read index.html")
    (resp/resource-response "index.html" {:root "resources"}))

(defroutes routes
           (GET "/" request rest-handler)
           (GET "/home" request wrapped-file-response))
```

I start `jetty` server as a typical `gradle` task

```
task startServer(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.lapots.platform.web.core'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

But it is unable to resolve `index.html` file. (`/` returns correct `rest response` message).

How to specify path to `html` page for `routes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show your `build.gradle` so I am unable to determine how your classpath is configured. If you are using defaults then the issue is that your `index.html` file is not available on classpath as it should be under `${rootDir}/src/main/resources` (which is a default location for resource/non-code files that should be included on classpath) and in `resources` subdirectory as your `ring.util.response/resource-response` `:root` is configured to `resource`.

Thus your `index.html` should be located under following path: `${rootDir}/src/main/resources/resources/index.html`.

Comment: Yes I was using defaults. Wow it works. But what are the best practises for `web` based application that does not rely on `clojurescript`?

Comment: The convention is to put your assets served by your HTTP server in a subdirectory on your classpath, usually named `public` (i.e. `${rootDir}/src/main/resources/public`. This isolates the classpath files that should and should not be available via HTTP.